# Is 'div' a Parameter or an Argument in JavaScript's document.createElement Method?

Tags: javascript, dom

In JavaScript's document.createElement('div'), is 'div' a parameter or an argument? While checking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement, I noticed the section titled "Parameters."

However, upon further research, I found other resources referring to it as "arguments." In the context of function calls in JavaScript, 'div' is an argument. You pass this string to specify the type of element you want to create. It is not considered a parameter when you are calling the createElement method. For instance, in document.createElement('div'), 'div' is the argument you provide to create a  element.

I also watched several YouTube tutorials. However, I noticed some inconsistency. Some video tutorials and other online resources describe 'div' as an 'argument.' This has led to some confusion on my part. I was expecting to find a consensus on the correct terminology to use in this context but instead found differing opinions.

Could you please clarify whether 'div' is considered a parameter or an argument in this context and why there might be such a discrepancy in the terminology used?

Your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: The terms "argument" and "parameter" are often used interchangeably in programming, however they have slightly different meanings. A parameter is a variable listed in the function's definition. For example, in `function formatString(str)`, `str` is a parameter. An argument is the value you assign to a parameter when calling a function. For example, in `formatString('my_string');`, `'my_string'` is an argument. So in your case, the value `'div'` is being passed in to the `createElement` function as an argument.